# Automatically add words if duplicate post titles

Tags: title

i have two post duplicate Post Titles: "Love Story".

i want code Automatically add a random words if Duplicate Post Titles, like post 2 duplicate Titles ==> auto change post 2 titles like: "Love Story Two".

and if user up post 3, duplicate Titles again => auto add random words in post titles like : "Love story three".

thanks a lot

Comment: When should these words be added? When the post is published?

Comment: WordPress doesn't care too much about duplication of post titles, it's the slugs that matter.

Comment: @KrzysiekDróżdż yes, When the post is published.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please give this a shot. I didn't test it, so let me know if it has any errors.
Basically, it will check the title before saving and run a loop checking to see if it can get a post by that title. If it can, it will add a new suffix and keep trying.

As you can see, you'll have to add more number to the `$suffixes` array to allow it go count farther. Alternatively, you could use The [`NumberFormatter`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.numberformatter.php) class if available.

```
add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data' , 'filter_post_title' , '99', 2 );
function filter_post_title( $data , $postarr ) {
    if( !$postarr['ID'] ) { // Publishing for the first time
        $suffixes = array( 'Two', 'Three', 'Four' );
        $count = 0;
        $original_title = $data['post_title'];
        $new_title = $original_title;
        while( get_page_by_title( $new_title, 'object', 'post' ) ) {
            $new_title = $original_title . " " . $suffixes[$count];
            $count++;
        }
        $data['post_title'] = $new_title;
    }
    return $data;
}
```

You could write it with fewer variables, but I feel this way is more readable.

**Edit:**
The downside to this is that it has to query the database each time it increments. So, to get to "Five" it would require five queries. If you start having it count to high numbers you will start to notice the saving process taking longer. In that case, querying all the posts that start with the current title and then parsing them to find the current number would be more efficient.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but it doesn't work. I added the code but published the post with duplicate titles, still not adding random words.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that `get_page_by_title()` needs to be set to look at posts. I tested it and it works now. Please test it with all save cases to make sure you don't get any unexpected results. It may not work perfectly, but it is a good start.

Comment: thank you so much, it work!!! <3<3<3

Comment: But there was a problem, when I edited and updated the post, "Post Titles + Two" changed "Post Title + Two + Two", meaning it would be changed every time I updated !! Is there any way Just change the title when publish, Updates are not altered title?

Comment: An `if` statement shoudl take care of that! I added it to the code, but didn't test it. Please let me know if there are issues. When this filter is executed, it is before the database query, so if the post is being saved to the database for the first time it will not have an ID yet. This `if` statement only runs our title replacement if this ID is not present.